# Openlayers loading starts if I use an hard coded id, but not if I'm using [id]

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

My component:

```html
<div>
  <label>Sélectionnez une commune :&nbsp;</label>
  <app-communes anneeCOG="2023"></app-communes>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let region of regions;">carte [id] = "environment[region + '_id']"
    [nom]="environment[region + '_nom']"
    [url_couche] = "environment[region + '_couche_url']"
    [layer_couche] = "environment[region + '_couche_layer']"
    [longitude] = "environment[region + '_longitude_initale']"
    [latitude] = "environment[region + '_latitude_initale']"
    [zoom] = "environment[region + '_zoom']"
    [projection] = "environment[region + '_projection']">
  </app-carte>
</div>
```

relies on an `environment.ts` file:

```html
  // Métropole
  metropole_id: 'carte_metropole',                                       // Identifiant de la carte (placé dans la balise)
  metropole_nom: 'Métropole',                                            // Nom de cette partie de carte
  metropole_couche_layer: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',           // Plan IGN V2
  metropole_couche_url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts', // Plan IGN V2, tuilé
  metropole_projection: 'EPSG:3857',                                     // Web Mercator projection
  metropole_latitude_initale: 46.53333333,                               // Centroïde de la France, d'après IGN en 1993 (Commune de Vesdun dans le Cher)
  metropole_longitude_initale: 2.41666667,
  metropole_zoom: 6,

  // Guadeloupe
  guadeloupe_id: 'carte_guadeloupe',
  guadeloupe_nom: 'Guadeloupe',
  guadeloupe_couche_layer: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
  guadeloupe_couche_url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts',
  guadeloupe_projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  guadeloupe_latitude_initale: 16.265,
  guadeloupe_longitude_initale: -61.551,
  guadeloupe_zoom: 9,

  // Martinique
  martinique_id: 'carte_martinique',
  martinique_nom: 'Martinique',
  martinique_couche_layer: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
  martinique_couche_url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts',
  martinique_projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  martinique_latitude_initale: 14.641528,
  martinique_longitude_initale: -61.024174,
  martinique_zoom: 9,

  // Guyane
  guyane_id: 'carte_guyane',
  guyane_nom: 'Guyane',
  guyane_couche_layer: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
  guyane_couche_url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts',
  guyane_projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  guyane_latitude_initale: 3.933889,
  guyane_longitude_initale: -53.125782,
  guyane_zoom: 8,

  // La Réunion
  la_reunion_id: 'carte_la_reunion',
  la_reunion_nom: 'La Réunion',
  la_reunion_couche_layer: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
  la_reunion_couche_url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts',
  la_reunion_projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  la_reunion_latitude_initale: -21.115141,
  la_reunion_longitude_initale: 55.536384,
  la_reunion_zoom: 9,

  // Mayotte
  mayotte_id: 'carte_mayotte',
  mayotte_nom: 'Mayotte',
  mayotte_couche_layer: 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2',
  mayotte_couche_url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts',
  mayotte_projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  mayotte_latitude_initale: -12.827500,
  mayotte_longitude_initale: 45.166244,
  mayotte_zoom: 9
```

and is implemented by:

```
export class CarteFranceComponent {
  protected readonly environment= environment;
  protected regions: string[] = ['metropole', 'guadeloupe', 'martinique', 'guyane', 'la_reunion', 'mayotte']
}
```

it uses an `app-carte` tag, whose html is limited to:

```html
<div class="{{id}}" id="{{id}}"></div>
```

and its implementation starts like that, for its initial loading part that causes me troubles:

```
export class CarteComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Identifiant de la carte (placé dans sa balise) */
  @Input() id!: string;

  /* Nom de cette carte */
  @Input() nom!: string;

  /* Longitude. */
  @Input() longitude!: number;

  /* Latitude. */
  @Input() latitude!: number;

  /** Niveau de zoom initial. */
  @Input() zoom!: number;

  /** Projection */
  @Input() projection!: string;

  /** URL de la couche à afficher initialement. */
  @Input() url_couche!: string;

  /** Layer de la couche à afficher initialement. */
  @Input() layer_couche!: string;

  /** Couche géographique à afficher */
  private couche_geographique: TileLayer<WMTS>;

  /** Map Openlayer */
  private coucheOpenLayer: Map;

  /**
   * Initialiser le composant carte
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Déclarer la couche, si elle n'est pas encore connue
    if (this.couche_geographique == null) {
      console.log(`Chargement initial de la carte '${this.nom}' avec la couche géographique '${this.layer_couche}' depuis l'URL ${this.url_couche}. Id de destination: '${this.id}'`)
      this.couche_geographique = this.declare_couche(this.url_couche, this.layer_couche, this.projection, 'image/png');
    }

    // Placer la couche demandée, aux coordonnées et zoom initiaux demandées
    console.log(`Initialisation de la carte '${this.nom}' (id: '${this.id}')`)

    this.coucheOpenLayer = new Map({
      layers: [ this.couche_geographique ],
      target: this.id,
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]),
        zoom: this.zoom,
        projection: this.projection
      })
    });

    this.coucheOpenLayer.on('loadstart', function() {
      console.log(`Début du chargement de la carte`)
    })

    this.coucheOpenLayer.on('loadend', function() {
      console.log(`Fin du chargement de la carte`)
    })

    this.coucheOpenLayer.on('error', function() {
      console.log(`Erreur de chargement de la carte`)
    })

  }
  [...]
```

When it runs, it displays on the console:

```
Démarrage environnement dev spark: http://localhost:9090 backend: http://localhost:9091 app.component.ts:14:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Métropole' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_metropole' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Métropole' (id: 'carte_metropole') carte.component.ts:63:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Guadeloupe' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_guadeloupe' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Guadeloupe' (id: 'carte_guadeloupe') carte.component.ts:63:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Martinique' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_martinique' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Martinique' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:63:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Guyane' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_guyane' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Guyane' (id: 'carte_guyane') carte.component.ts:63:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'La Réunion' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_la_reunion' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'La Réunion' (id: 'carte_la_reunion') carte.component.ts:63:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Mayotte' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_mayotte' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Mayotte' (id: 'carte_mayotte')
```

A breakpoint, at a point of the regions loop (i.e: on 'Martinique', id: 'carte_martinique') displays correct values:

[image]

And doing an HTML inspection, I see:

[image]

There's no *openlayers* loading at all.

But, if I impose a `this.id = 'carte_martinique'` in `ngOnInit()`:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Déclarer la couche, si elle n'est pas encore connue
    if (this.couche_geographique == null) {
      console.log(`Chargement initial de la carte '${this.nom}' avec la couche géographique '${this.layer_couche}' depuis l'URL ${this.url_couche}. Id de destination: '${this.id}'`)
      this.couche_geographique = this.declare_couche(this.url_couche, this.layer_couche, this.projection, 'image/png');
    }

    this.id = "carte_martinique";

    // Placer la couche demandée, aux coordonnées et zoom initiaux demandées
    console.log(`Initialisation de la carte '${this.nom}' (id: '${this.id}')`)

    this.coucheOpenLayer = new Map({
      layers: [ this.couche_geographique ],
      target: this.id,
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([this.longitude, this.latitude]),
        zoom: this.zoom,
        projection: this.projection
      })
    });
```

the openlayers loading is starting.

```
Chargement initial de la carte 'Métropole' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_metropole' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Métropole' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:65:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Guadeloupe' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_guadeloupe' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Guadeloupe' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:65:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Martinique' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_martinique' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Martinique' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:65:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Guyane' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_guyane' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Guyane' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:65:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'La Réunion' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_la_reunion' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'La Réunion' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:65:12
Chargement initial de la carte 'Mayotte' avec la couche géographique 'GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.PLANIGNV2' depuis l'URL https://wxs.ign.fr/decouverte/geoportail/wmts. Id de destination: 'carte_mayotte' carte.component.ts:58:14
Initialisation de la carte 'Mayotte' (id: 'carte_martinique') carte.component.ts:65:12
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode. core.mjs:25520:16
Début du chargement de la carte 
Fin du chargement de la carte
```

And I can see `ol-viewport` div gathering under the first div having for id `carte_martinique` (that they all have now):

[image]

I can reproduce this problem in various manners:

if I change the `<div>` of `<app-carte>` with `<div [ngClass]="id" [id]="id" ></div>` it doesn't work, it outputs:

```html
<div _ngcontent-upu-c49="" ng-reflect-ng-class="carte_martinique" 
id="carte_martinique" class="carte_martinique"></div>
```

but if I write: `<div class="carte_martinique" id="carte_martinique" ></div>`, it will work and outputs:

```html
<div _ngcontent-xpk-c49="" id="carte_martinique" class="carte_martinique">
<div class="ol-viewport" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;" class="ol-unselectable ol-layers">
<div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><canvas style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top 0px; transform: matrix(0.75, 0, 0, 0.75, -0.125, -0.125);" width="427" height="427"></canvas>
</div></div>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;" class="ol-overlaycontainer">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;" class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent">
<div style="pointer-events: auto;" class="ol-zoom ol-unselectable ol-control">
<button class="ol-zoom-in" type="button" title="Zoom in">+</button>
<button class="ol-zoom-out" type="button" title="Zoom out">–</button></div>
<div style="pointer-events: auto;" class="ol-rotate ol-unselectable ol-control ol-hidden"><button class="ol-rotate-reset" type="button" title="Reset rotation"><span class="ol-compass" style="transform: rotate(0rad);">⇧</span>
</button></div>
<div style="pointer-events: auto; display: none;" class="ol-attribution ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed"><button type="button" aria-expanded="false" title="Attributions"><span class="ol-attribution-expand">i</span></button><ul></ul>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Why, when I'm using `this.id` inside a loop, an id `carte_martinique` isn't taken it into account by openlayers,
but if I hardcode it, it does?